# Finding column in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to write A method, getColumn, that takes as input an array of integer arrays as well as an index, j and returns an integer array corresponding to the j'th column in the array of arrays.

This is what I have so far. Any help completing this would be appreciated.

```
public static int[] getColumn(int[][] grid, int j) {

    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++ ) {
        int n = grid[row].length;
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {




        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "This is what I have so far" - and what results does this give you, vs what you would expect? What have you tried beyond that code, and how did that fail?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two loops, if you think about as a grid.

```
6 7 8 9  
6 7 8 9
6 7 8 9
```

for each row if you want the 0th column

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>()
for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++ ) {
   list.add(grid[i][0])
}
return list.toArray()
```

and just substitute j for 0 in this example and you wold get 6,6,6 as your result